# How to compile glibc for use without an operating system

Tags: linker, compilation, glibc

I would like to compile the functions of glibc to an object file which will then be linked to a program which I am running on a computer without any operating system. Some functions, such as `open`, I want to just fail with `ENOSYS`. Other functions I will write myself, such as `putchar`, and then have glibc use those functions in it's own (like `printf`). I also want to use functions that don't need a file system or process management system or anything like that, such as `strlen`. How can I do this?

Comment: If you do not get any better answers, check out [EGLIBC](http://www.eglibc.org/) and ask on their mailing list.  (I do not recommend trying to get help from the GNU libc maintainers...)

Answer (score 0):

Most C libraries rely on the kernel heavily, so it's not reasonable to port 'em. But since most of it doesn't need to be implemented, you can get away easily with a few prototypes for stubs and gcc builtins.

You can implement stubs easily using weak symbols:

```
#define STUB __attribute__((weak, alias("__stub"))) int
#define STUB_PTR __attribute__((weak, alias("__stub0"))) void *
int __stub();
void *__stub0();
```

Then defining the prototypes becomes trivial:

```
STUB read(int, void*, int);
STUB printf(const char *, ...);
STUB_PTR mmap(void*, int, int, int, int, int);
```

And the actual functions could be:

```
int __stub()
{
    errno = ENOSYS;
    return -1;
}

void *__stub0()
{
    errno = ENOSYS;
    return NULL;
}
```

If you need some non-trivial function, like `printf`, take it from uClibc instead of glibc (or some other smaller implementation).